# Android system battery drain

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, battery, bugs, troubleshooting

My android phone has heavy abnormal battery drains coming from Android system. **2000mAh and above on a single charge! I know for certain this is a software issue and not hardware.**

Before I hit the sack. Battery was around 96%, next morning 80%! Normal overnight drains on my mobile model is 1-2%, I am having around 15%.

1. During sleep, All my radios are usually off (WiFi, NFC, Bluetooth, Data, location), except phone.
2. My phone seems to be in deep sleep a good portion of that time (See WLD statistics - attachment #1).
3. Android system sucks my battery during sleep and it was at 90% relative consumption when I woke up (See screen shot #1, **Android sys has consumed 1840mAh in such a short time span!! This is ridiculously high for a phone that is apparently in Deep Sleep!**)
4. Also attached screen shots from WLD for Summary, Kernal / Partial wakelocks & Alarms.
5. Device is rooted.
6. Google sync is off, Backup is off.

I have searched all over. Read numerous threads from numerous forums. Some users have faced this issue on the same ROM while some others haven't. I have done my "homework". But this is one issue that I do not see any solutions wherever I look. I have searched days, not hours!!

Hence I decided to post over here. This is my hail mary attempt at solving this. If the experts here can't solve it, then I guess it would be pointless to search anymore.

**What is the issue that is causing this battery drain from Android System?**
I have noted that many users using my model (Huawei Mate 8) do not face this issue, while some users do face it.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you recently updated android via OTA or such things, when drain started did you installed some app right before that?
Try cleaning cache and rebooting.
Also you can use app Wakelock Detector to see what drains your battery, to see exactly what drains battery not just to show you that is Android system. Factory reset probably would help but save that when you run out of ideas.

Comment: Have you tried to switch off your phone and then turn it on again?

Comment: I have tried restarting, device several times.

Comment: I completely flashed a new stock ROM. So installed multiple apps. Interestingly, after installing quite often the battery is fine on the first charge. But after second charge there is heavy consumption. Wakelock detector does not help much since i do not have that many wakelocks from apps. I have optimized my phone such that only Whatsapp runs and couple of other low battery consumption apps. All other apps gets closed on screen lock.

Comment: I think that your phone is unable to receive much phone signal at night. I also had once faced this issue and found that the culprit was that there was very low signal, so the device will increase its cellular radio's amplitude thus draining more battery power. See the signal bars at night.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling automatic app updates has, for me, solved a severe battery drain problem that started a few days ago. Huawei P9.

For me Google Play Services and AndroidOS were the top users of battery.